# My render output is black even after trying some tricks

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

First i render animation as png which came well and then i tried video format with different camera angle but it playing previous one only instead of new one so i deleted them all and rendered, but this time the render output is black for both video and image formats
Then i googled and found this article in the link given below, i checked everything they asked to check all are good

But still my render is black

Link to my file= https://blend-exchange.com/b/wZwROZ9A

[https://artisticrender.com/why-is-my-render-black-in-blender/#:~:text=The%20surface%20and%20environment%20filters,on%20your%20video%20sequencer%20timeline](https://artisticrender.com/why-is-my-render-black-in-blender/#:%7E:text=The%20surface%20and%20environment%20filters,on%20your%20video%20sequencer%20timeline)

Answer (score 1):

You have a video strip loaded in the *Video Sequencer*, it's what's going to be rendered, so either remove it or disable the *Sequencer* option in the *Output* panel:

[image]